# Does the object include the preposition or not?

Tags: prepositions, objects

> Don’t be afraid of making mistakes in speaking English.

Is this the structure of 
[verb phrase: don’t be afraid **of**][object: making mistakes]
or 
[verb phrase: don’t be afraid][object: **of** making mistakes]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiom *be afraid of* is ambiguous, and how you parse it depends on what you want to do with it.

1. One approach is to treat the entire phrase as a ‘phrasal verb’ equivalent to the lexical verb *fear*:

   > Don't *fear* [making mistakes]

   On this reading, the bracketed non-finite clause is the Direct Object of the verb. This reading is supported by recasting the sentence as a question:

   > What *do you fear*?
   >   What *are you afraid of*?
2. Another, very traditional, approach is to treat *be* as the ordinary ‘linking verb’ (copula), with *afraid* as its subject complement. This is clearer if we recast the sentence from the imperative into the indicative mood:

   > You are *afraid* [of making mistakes].

   On this reading, *of making mistakes* is a prepositional phrase modifying *afraid*. This reading is supported by replacing *afraid* with similar adjectives; note that in each the prepositional phrase can be deleted and a well-formed sentence remains.

   > You are *frightened* [of making mistakes]. 
   >   You are *proud* [of making mistakes].
   >   You are *sad* [at making mistakes].
   >   You are *embarrassed* [at making mistakes].
3. Note, however, that some of those adjectives take a different preposition. This leads me to suggest that a third approach is possible here. *Afraid of* is a ‘phrasal adjective’ which differs from the base lexical adjective in that it ***takes an object representing its agent***:

   > You are *afraid of* [making mistakes] = Making mistakes makes you afraid.
   >   You are *proud of* [making mistakes] = Making mistakes makes you proud.
   >   You are *sad at* [making mistakes] = Making mistakes makes you sad.
   >   You are *embarrassed at* [making mistakes] = Making mistakes makes you embarassed.

   This is in effect to see such ‘phrasal adjectives’ as equivalent to past participles of active verbs—which is in fact the case with *embarassed*! *Don't be afraid of making mistakes* is then the equivalent of:

   > Don't be frightened by making mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, *object* is a, "noun or noun phrase governed by an active transitive verb or by a preposition."
It doesn't include the preposition.